# How to decode .gz files using Microsoft Access VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, gzip

I have some files which need reading using Access / VBA. They are compressed using ".gz" compression. How can I read those files in?

I figure this must be a solved problem but alas can't find anything. Command-line would be one option but it would involve the users of the VBA application having to have particular tools installed. Perhaps there is a library I can just include, which I can then ship with my VBA application (.accdr)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few libraries around, however, probably the most popular is [zlib](http://www.zlib.net). A nice example using zlib, albeit written in VB6 (which shouldn't be too difficult to convert to VBA) is located [here](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Libraries/Compression/Compressing_and_Expanding_With_zLib/article.asp). One nice point about zlib is that it doesn't need registering (i.e. `REGSVR*`), so you should be able to drop it into the same folder as your DB (or even embed it into the DB then extract it automatically).