# Error when extracting gz to zip file using vba

Tags: excel, vba, zip, gzip

I want to download .csv file from this site (https://bulk.meteostat.net/v2/hourly/41024.csv.gz)
And this is document for data (https://dev.meteostat.net/bulk/hourly.html)

This is my code.
I can't use any other program like winzip32 because I should share it to the others.
So I first tried to convert .gz file to .zip and tried to unzip file.
But It doesn't work at all. Is there any problem to my code?

Is there any workaround for unzipping .gz file using vba? I searched all but there was only winzip32 method..

```
Sub getResult()


    Dim station As String
    Dim startYear As String
    Dim endYear As String
    
    startYear = "2018"
    endYear = "2022"
    
    station = 41024
    makeFolder ("C:\myfile\")
    
    Call DownloadFile(startYear, endYear, station)

End Sub


Sub makeFolder(url As String)
    If Dir(url, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir (url)
    Else
    End If
End Sub

Sub DownloadFile(startYear As String, endYear As String, station As String)

    Dim year As Integer
    
    For year = CInt(startYear) To CInt(endYear)
    
        Dim myURL As String
        Dim path As String
        Dim path2 As String
        Dim file As String
        
        myURL = "https://bulk.meteostat.net/v2/hourly/" & startYear & "/" & station & ".csv.gz"
        path = "C:\myfile\" & station
        path2 = path & "\" & year
        
        
        Dim WinHttpReq As Object
        Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, "username", "password"
        WinHttpReq.send
        
        If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
            Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            oStream.Open
            oStream.Type = 1
            oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
            makeFolder (path)
            makeFolder (path2)
            file = path2 & "\" & station & ".csv.zip"
            

            oStream.SaveToFile file, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
            oStream.Close
            
            Call Unzip(path2, file)
        End If

    Next year

End Sub





Private Sub Unzip(path As String, filepath As String)
Dim FSO As Object
Dim sfolder As String
Dim sApp As Object
Dim MyFile As String
Dim ExtractTo As Variant
Dim fileName As String
Dim objZipItems As FolderItems

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ExtractTo = path & "\Extracted"
    If Len(Dir(ExtractTo, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir ExtractTo
    End If

    MyFile = Dir(filepath, vbNormal)
    Do While MyFile <> ""
        If Right(MyFile, 3) = "zip" Then
        Set sApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        Set objZipItems = sApp.Namespace(path).items
       sApp.Namespace(ExtractTo).CopyHere objZipItems
        DoEvents
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Try this  ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827578/how-to-decode-gz-files-using-microsoft-access-vba

Comment: You can try the tar command see https://ss64.com/nt/tar.html